# Google Sheets - Find all occurrences of target over 2d RANGE, select other value in row when found

Tags: google-sheets, search, filter

Please see the attached example: [Sheets Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SM_Z1dID4orPg4Yh0PIeNWaX2fdNgYN6AunLZWUVtiY/edit?usp=sharing)

For this example, assume we receive the first tab (Awards List) as data. Column A is names of awards, Columns C through E represent up to 3 possible winners per awards.

Assume we also have Column A in the second tab, (awards per person), where the column is a list of all award titles.

I would like to write a formula for the data you see in Column C. This formula would at the names in Column A in "Awards Per Person" tab, search for all occurrences of the names through columns C through E in tab "Awards List" and produce a single cell listing of all awards won by the names in Column A in "Awards Per Person" as demonstrated in the link above.

Thanks!

I have been tinkering with vlookup, index/match, textjoin etc. and am having zero luck - I think because the search area is 2D instead of a single column or row. Any way I can do this without a macro/code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAP to go through each name, FILTER to find the awards and inside of it BYROW to see if there's a match with the name in each row. Then TEXTJOIN will concatenate the values:

```
=MAP(A3:A, LAMBDA(name,IF(name="","",TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFNA(FILTER('Awards List'!A3:A,BYROW('Awards List'!C3:E, LAMBDA(r,IFNA(MATCH(name, r,0),0)>0)))),))))
```

[image]

The use of BYROW allows you to create a column with TRUE or FALSE if the name is met in each row. This way, column A of awards will be filtered according to it

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try to the following formula-

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A3:A,1),LAMBDA(x,
TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER('Awards List'!A3:A,MMULT(INDEX(--('Awards List'!C3:E=x)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS('Awards List'!C3:E3),1,1,0))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=map(A3:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,textjoin(", ",1,index(if('Awards List'!C3:E=Σ,'Awards List'!A3:A,))))))
```

[image]